# LaTeX - How to limit the number of characters in a calculated Textfield with hyperref package

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, textfield

I am creating a simple form where people should enter their height and weight with auto-calculation of the corresponding BMI. For this use, I use the option "calculate" from \TextField in the hyperref package.

The calculation goes well, but the answer provided gives a number with all decimals (eg. 22.491349480...) and I would like **only the first decimal to appear** (-> 24.4), and (if possible) the **best output** beeing a rounded number for the first decimal (->24.5).

The "maxlen=4" command works only when I click inside the field, but the printout is still with all the decimals.

I also tried to change the width of the field, which effectively cuts the answer, but it is impossible to fix a precise width that would show all the different possible lengths.

Would anyone have an idea on how to do this ?

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\noindent
\TextField[name=hight,align=0]{Hight [cm]}
\\

\TextField[name=weight,align=0]{Weight [kg]}
\\

\noindent
\TextField[name=BMI, maxlen=4,align=0,readonly=true,
           calculate={%
                      var f_hight = this.getField("hight");
                      var f_weight = this.getField("weight");
                      event.value = f_weight.value /((f_hight.value/100)* 
   (f_hight.value/100));
                       }]{BMI}


\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: BMIcalculator]

Comment: Most likely, you have to restrict the number output within the JavaScript code of the field

Comment: shouldn't it be "height" (not related to underlying question)

Comment: Definitively should be. I mistranslated from my original code, which is not in english. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\noindent
\TextField[name=hight,align=0]{Hight [cm]}
\\

\TextField[name=weight,align=0]{Weight [kg]}
\\

\noindent
\TextField[name=BMI, maxlen=4,align=0,readonly=true,
           calculate={%
                      var f_hight = this.getField("hight");
                      var f_weight = this.getField("weight");
                      var n = f_weight.value /((f_hight.value/100)*
   (f_hight.value/100));
   event.value = n.toFixed(2);
                       }]{BMI}


\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]